# Docker container exited instantly with code (127)

Tags: docker, containers, lib

In the log file I have this error:

```
./worker: error while loading shared libraries: libcares.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried everything with the library it exists and its linked to the path.
My Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt update -y && apt install libssl-dev -y
WORKDIR /worker
COPY build/worker ./
COPY build/lib /usr/lib
EXPOSE 50051
CMD ./worker
```

My makefile:

```
all: clean build
build: 
    mkdir -p build/lib && \
    cd build && cmake .. && make

clean:
    rm -rf build

clean-containers : 
    docker container stop `docker container ls -aq`
    docker container rm `docker container ls -a -q`

create-workers : 
    docker run --name worker1 -p 2001:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker2 -p 2002:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker3 -p 2003:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker4 -p 2004:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker5 -p 2005:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker6 -p 2006:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker7 -p 2007:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker8 -p 2008:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker9 -p 2009:50051 -d workerimage
    docker run --name worker10 -p 2010:50051 -d workerimage
```

Comment: Can you verify the file `libcares.so.2` exists inside `/usr/lib/` of the container ?

Comment: no I cannot find it

Comment: try `find . -type f -name "libcares.so*"` inside the container

Comment: I'm sorry but I am new to docker , please where I can find the container /usr/lib

Comment: try `docker run --rm -ti IMAGE find /usr/lib -type f -name "libcares.so*"`

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: So the missing `libcares.so.2` is your problem. I'm assuming `COPY build/lib /usr/lib` should copy `libcares.so.2` over but doesn't you have to find out why it's not in your local `build/lib` directory

Comment: Thank you sir very mcuh for your help.I get it; In fact  libcares.so.2 needs the libcares.so.2.2.0 also to be in the build/lib

Answer (score 0):

make sure `libcares.so.2` and other shared libraries are present inside `/usr/lib` of the container.